# Get real-time heart rate watchOS 4 without iPhone

Tags: real-time, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit, heartrate

I'm writing a heart rate BPM-alert application for the Apple Watch. Its function is to vibrate the watch when the user's heart rate is over some BPM threshold during a workout.

**What is the most real-time way to get heart rate data on the watch?** Beat-by-beat would be best but updates every ~5 seconds would suffice. I do not need any of this data on the iPhone since the only use I have is to vibrate the watch the moment BPM is too high. I'm targeting watchOS 4 on the Series 1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API on watchOS to get beat-by-beat heart rate measurements, but you can stream live heart rate measurements with `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`. If you want your app to record heart rate in the background, even when the screen is off, then your app must start an `HKWorkoutSession`.